# No puedo instalar xlrd

Tags: python, cmd, ssl, pip, xlrd

No puedo instalar el paquete *xlrd* me sale esto en mi cmd:

```
C:\Users\VICTOR>pip install xlrd
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1122)'))': /simple/xlrd/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1122)'))': /simple/xlrd/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1122)'))': /simple/xlrd/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1122)'))': /simple/xlrd/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1122)'))': /simple/xlrd/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/xlrd/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/xlrd/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1122)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xlrd
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xlrd
```

Answer (score 1):

El error te están indicando que tienes problemas para conectarte con **pypi**. Este error viene porque tienes una versión desactualizada de `pip`. Tienes que actualizar `pip` para ello utiliza este comando para **hacerlo desde la web oficial**:

```
pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

Después ya puedes instalar el paquete que desees.

Comment: tengo internet por proxy
eh hasta ahora todos los comandos que he descargado se instalaron bien. mi pip esta actualizado.
gracias...

Comment: Si es el proxy el que está bloqueando el acceso debes desconectarte del proxy y hacerlo sin él, o configurar el proxy para que permita la descarga.